# Is there anyway to check if my app calls any method exclusive for iOS 8?

Tags: ios7, ios8

After testing my app in a iOS 7 device, I got a crash calling containsString from NSString, and then I realised that that methods has NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);

Is there anyway to check automatically my program to see if there is any other method that is not available in iOS 7?
How is possible to compile and app with deployment target of 7.0 and not saying any warning or error in these cases?

-[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702297c0
2015-10-23 12:03:37.655 WA[1434:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702297c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183bd2f50 0x1900dc1fc 0x183bd7c04 0x183bd5930 0x183af55dc 0x1002a2c08 0x1000c71dc 0x1000caa88 0x1000c69bc 0x1000f3a4c 0x186c1055c 0x186c0ff08 0x186c099ec 0x186b9d8cc 0x186b9cad0 0x186c09044 0x1897bb504 0x1897bb030 0x183b92e90 0x183b92df0 0x183b91014 0x183ad1c20 0x186c081c8 0x186c02fdc 0x1000b6040 0x1906cfaa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: If you have the deployment target set to iOS 7, then I would have expected the compiler to generate warnings.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for reply. I double checked the warnings I have and I see nothing about NSString or containsString. And when my app is launched, immediately it crashes.

Comment: And you're certain the deployment target is being correctly set?

Comment: Yes, I checked again. That's the reason I don't understand why I don't receive any warning. Apart from that my iPhone has ios7 and the app runs (or tries).

Answer (score 0):

You should use rangeOfString instead of containsString. Since rangeOfString available from iOS 2.0, you will not get crash on this.

Code snippets,

```
NSString *string = @"https://www.google.co.in/";
NSString *substring = @"http";
if ([oneContent rangeOfString:subString].location == NSNotFound) {
   NSLog(@"string does not contain substring");
} else {
   NSLog(@"string contains substring!");
}
```

Otherwise you can add category class for NSString and have a method like containsString: where you can implement the above code. It'll work dynamically.

Comment: Yes I know, actually that's what I'm doing right now, but the question is another.

Comment: @Ricardo Edited my answer.